# how to get the language of the project in SonarQube custom plugin

Tags: ruby, sonarqube, erb

For SonarQube, I have developed several custom plugins (several languages), including custom erb UI.

I wish to activate several plugins at the same time, then detect the language of the current project in the erb file.

The `project.key` retrieves the unique key (`project.language` doesn't work).

Is it possible to retrieve the language of the current project?

Comment: Since SonarQube 4.2 projects are multi-language so project.language is more or less deprecated. I don't understand "detect the language of the current project in the erb file"

Comment: Thanks Julien, it is deprecated since SQ 4.2, I'll try another way.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SonarQube does it like this in the erb file:

`languages = Api::Utils.java_facade.getLanguages()
languages_by_key = Hash[languages.collect { |l| [l.getKey(), l.getName] }]`

Haven't tried this myself, but I see no reason why this shouldn't work.
See [SonarQube Size Widget](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-server/src/main/resources/org/sonar/server/dashboard/widget/size.html.erb)